# How to drop single quotes, and add brackets into pandas dataframe after converting to_json?

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests, api-design

I have successfully converted a pandas dataframe into a json string while adding the string 'import_data' at the beginning like so:

```
a = {"import_data" : df.to_json(orient='records')}
```

This returns:

```
{'import_data': '[{"\\ufeffemail_addresses":"test@test.com","first_name":"test","last_name":"test","lists":1234567890},{"\\ufeffemail_addresses":"Jane@Doe.com","first_name":"Jane","last_name":"Doe","lists":1234567890},{"\\ufeffemail_addresses":"Pradeep@Patel.com","first_name":"Pradeep","last_name":"Patel","lists":1234567890}]'}
```

However pandas `'to_json'`, isnt converting the dataframe exactly too what I need to pass into an API.

The string need, has to look like this:

```
update_contact = '{"import_data": [{"email_addresses": ["test@test.com"],"first_name": "test","last_name": "test"},{"email_addresses": ["Jane@Doe.com"],"first_name": "Jane","last_name": "Doe"}, {"email_addresses": ["Pradeep@Patel.com"],"first_name": "Pradeep","last_name": "Patel"}],"lists": ["1234567890"]}'
```

`to_json` is adding single quote around the first bracket, adding backslashes for some reason, the letter 'u', and a string `\\ufeff`at the beginning of `email_address`. Not sure how to drop all of this.

Edit:

This is how I can only pass data into the API:

```
headers = {

        'Authorization': 'Bearer x',
        'X-Originating-Ip': 'x',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',

        }


update_contact = '{"import_data": [{"email_addresses": ["test@test.com"],"first_name": "test","last_name": "test"},{"email_addresses": ["Jane@Doe.com"],"first_name": "Jane","last_name": "Doe"}, {"email_addresses": ["Pradeep@Patel.com"],"first_name": "Pradeep","last_name": "Patel"}],"lists": ["1072830671"]}'

r_3 = requests.post('urlapi_key=x', headers=headers ,data = update_contact)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
update_contact = '{\"import_data\": [{\"email_addresses\": [\"test@test.com\"],\"first_name\": \"test\",\"last_name\": \"test\"},{\"email_addresses\": [\"Jane@Doe.com\"],\"first_name\": \"Jane\",\"last_name\": \"Doe\"}, {\"email_addresses\": [\"Pradeep@Patel.com\"],\"first_name\": \"Pradeep\",\"last_name\": \"Patel\"}],\"lists\": [\"1234567890\"]}'
```

We can use backslash`\`before doublequote `"` to print it like this `\"`

Comment: Thank you for the response. but the api I am passing the variable is not able to parse that line. I will make a edit ot show you how I pass into API.